# Vala examples compile errors

Tags: windows, vala, pkg-config, msys2

Installed Vala for Windows64 from the MSYS2 project. Started running various examples from https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Examples. Some examples produce errors like

... the "Clutter Samples:Animated Actors"

```
D:\Projects\Vala\Examples>valac.exe --version
Vala 0.36.1-dirty

D:\Projects\Vala\Examples>valac.exe --pkg clutter-1.0 clutter.vala -o clutter.exe
D:/Projects/Vala/Examples/clutter.vala.c:7:29: fatal error: clutter/clutter.h: No such file or direc
tory
 #include <clutter/clutter.h>
                             ^
compilation terminated.
error: cc exited with status 1
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

... and the "Vala GTK+ 3.x Examples: Basic Sample"

```
D:\Projects\Vala\Examples>valac.exe --version
Vala 0.36.1-dirty

D:\Projects\Vala\Examples>valac.exe --pkg gtk+-3.0 gtk+3-hello.vala -o gtk+3-hello.exe
D:/Projects/Vala/Examples/gtk+3-hello.vala.c:17:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or director
y

                     ^
compilation terminated.
error: cc exited with status 1
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

...and the Vala Collections: libgee sample

```
D:\Projects\Vala\Examples>valac.exe --version
Vala 0.36.1-dirty

D:\Projects\Vala\Examples>valac.exe --pkg=gee-0.8 libgee-collections.vala -o libgee-collections.exe

error: Package `gee-0.8' not found in specified Vala API directories or GObject-Introspection GIR di
rectories
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

I realize pkg:gee-0.8 is not installed, but I did find 0.20.0-1 using pacman. I dont know how to reference this library?

```
$ pacman -Ss gee -v
Root      : /
Conf File : /etc/pacman.conf
DB Path   : /var/lib/pacman/
Cache Dirs: /var/cache/pacman/pkg/
Hook Dirs : /usr/share/libalpm/hooks/  /etc/pacman.d/hooks/
Lock File : /var/lib/pacman/db.lck
Log File  : /var/log/pacman.log
GPG Dir   : /etc/pacman.d/gnupg/
Targets   : gee
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-libgee 0.20.0-1
    A collection library providing GObject-based interfaces and classes for
    commonly used data structures (mingw-w64)
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-libgee 0.20.0-1
    A collection library providing GObject-based interfaces and classes for
    commonly used data structures (mingw-w64)
```

Obviously my installation is incorrect/incomplete. What do I need to change or install to fix these type of issues?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `valac.exe` directly can be a problem.

Usually when using msys2 to compile something you first enter the msys2 shell with the `MSYSTEM` environment variable set up correctly. (there are scripts and in newer versions executables in the msys2 root folder that can do that for you).

For example when you set `MSYSTEM=MINGW64` (caveat: `MINGW64` must be upper case!) and then run `mingtty.exe` or `bash.exe --login` you can then check your `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` var:

```
$ echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
/mingw64/lib/pkgconfig:/mingw64/share/pkgconfig
```

Be sure to understand the difference of the three `MSYSTEM` settings:

- MSYS - Only used to bootstrap the core msys2 system and for packaging purposes
- MINGW32 / MINGW64 - The "normal" environment (32-Bit / 64-Bit) you work in when using msys2.

The `pacman` package names for the different `MSYSTEM` environment have prefixes. I.e. the packages that start with `mingw-w64-x86_64` are used in the `MSYSTEM=MINGW64` environment.

`vala` uses `pkg-config` (be sure to have `mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-pkg-config` installed) when you specify something with `--pkg` and `pkg-config` then searches for `.pc` files (like `gee-0.8.pc`).

The `mingw-w64-x86_64-libgee` package installs its pc file as `/mingw64/lib/pkgconfig/gee-0.8.pc`.

Answer (score 0):

With `gee-0.8` the `0.8` is the interface version number, not the release version number. So install release 0.20.0 and the relevant interface files should become available. That also applies to Clutter and GTK+3.